# determing the string containg the date is of US format or of UK format

Tags: java, date

I have one question is that lets say I have a string which is as shown below

```
String d = "03/03/2015"
```

now i wanted to know that string that stores tyhe date is of  UK format date or US format date ,  so for that i want to build a logic which will scan the value from the second forward slash ,  lets say in this from the second slash the value is `03` so it will scan the value from the second forward slash and if this value is less or equal to `12` then this is month else this is date as date can be `30` or `3`1 .

please advise is there any hack or way i can implement to detect whether the string store the date is of  US format `MM/dd/yyyy` or it is UK format that is  `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: Well, 03/04/2015 can be both, no?

Comment: @MarounMaroun perfect completely agree with you , thats the problem has java got that much intellisense..?

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to do.. Please try to be clearer.

Comment: Along came ISO8601 and ISO8601-ext. Anybody who uses a format other than those needs a stern talking to. In your case you don't know unless you have a population of dates where at least one of them is not ambiguous. But that strategy is too risky IMHO to be used in production.

Comment: This isn't really a Java issue - I'm not sure how anybody or thing could be expected to determine if 03/04/2015 is US or UK format.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you can't determine if that `String` is a US or UK date. You would be able to see if it is if the first 03 or second 03 was above 12 and one wasn't as there are only 12 months in the year (duh!).

EDIT - Date doesn't have a locale, was getting mixed up with a `DateFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that, except if you have a bunch of dates of the EXACT same type, and you are ABSOLUTELY sure that at least one of them contains a day higher than 12 .